# Specific Columns to Txt yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to cobble together a script in order to process many excel spreadsheets formatting a specific way. The second portion of the script is working fine, but I need help first converting specific columns (the number of and position could change in the future, so i want to explicitly name the columns in the code) to txt based yyyy-mm-dd because the code outputs a csv file, but the csv file uses regional date formatting. There is also one column, column 7, that is date time and I want to trim the time off. Finally, i need to use a cell range that doesn't include the date column headers. Currently column 1 literally forces all cells to read as "YYYY-MM-DD", and all other date columns read correctly in excel but convert back to regional dates on export. Thanks so much.

```
    Sub CSVFile()
    Columns(1).NumberFormat = ”@”
    Columns(1).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(7).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(8).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(9).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(11).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(16).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(28).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(29).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(31).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(33).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(36).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(39).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(40).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(44).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(45).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(48).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(49).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    Columns(50).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
Dim SrcRg As Range
Dim CurrRow As Range
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim CurrTextStr As String
Dim ListSep As String
Dim FName As Variant
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")
ListSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
  If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
  Set SrcRg = Selection
  Else
  Set SrcRg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End If
Open FName For Output As #1
For Each CurrRow In SrcRg.Rows
  CurrTextStr = ìî
For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
  If (CurrCell.Value = “NULL” Or Len(CurrCell.Value) < 1) Then
  CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & ListSep
  Else
  CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & “”“” & Replace(CurrCell.Value, “”“”, “”“”“”) & “”“” & ListSep 
  End If
Next
While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
  CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
Wend
Print #1, CurrTextStr
Next
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not really super-clear exactly what the problem is, but changing `CurrCell.Value` to `CurrCell.Text` would give you more control over the output (since the Text property reflects the current cell number format)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but something i noticed to make your live a little easier (hopefully) `Range("A,G:I,P,H,J:K,M:N").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`, take this example to suit your needs.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly (it's horribly hard to read) and make sure you don't use these fancy quotes `“”` which are not allowed in VBA and throw an exception. Replace them with the regular quotes `""`. Please [edit] your question to fix it.